# Use T-SQL to create a linked server between localhost and a cloud server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I have an SQL database that is hosted in the cloud on a server which I don't have any control over. I can connect to that server and view my database through Management Studio using a URL similar to `reports.theremotesite.net` and using SQL Authentication.

I want to query some of the Views provided by that database and copy the resulting rows to a local database held on my machine. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 locally.
My research indicates that setting up a linked server is the first step to doing this but I have been struggling to get one set up using T-SQL.

*(I know that you can set them up through Management Studio but my ultimate goal is to have this as a stored procedure in my local database which is called every night so I've been trying to make it entirely script based. Am I making a mistake?)*

I have read the documentation on [sp_addlinkedserver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) and [sp_addlinkedsrvlogin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms189811.aspx) but I didn't fully understand where to put the different parameters in the script.

Example server details:

> **Server name**: reports.theremotesite.net
>   **Authentication**: SQL Server Authentication
>   **Login**: MyUsername
>   **Password**: MyPassword
>   **Database**: MyRemoteDatabase

Local details:

> **Server name**: localhost
>   **Authentication**: Windows Authentication
>   **Database**: MyLocalDatabase

My script structure is like this:

```
USE [master];
GO

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'localhost', 
    @srvproduct = N'', 
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
    @datasrc = N'tcp:reports.theremotesite.net', 
    @catalog = N'master';

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'reports.theremotesite.net',
    @useself = N'False',
    @locallogin = NULL,
    @rmtuser = 'MyUsername'
    @rmtpassword = 'MyPassword';
GO
```

When I run the script I get the following error:

> The server 'reports.theremotesite.net' does not exist. Use sp_helpserver to show available servers.

Running sp_helpserver shows 2 rows, one with my machine name and one called localhost which I assume is the result of the script even though it didn't complete.

Any help or pointers would be marvellous as I am totally lost!

Comment: The first Execute statement completed successfully resulting in the creation of the "localhost" linked server.  @server is not the name of the server you're creating it on, but the name of the linked server object you're creating.  I suggest you drop that, swap "localhost" with "reports.theremotesite.net" and rerun both sets of statements.

Comment: On what line do you get the error? I suspect it's the second one. `@rmtsrvname` is the name of the linked server you created, not its address. Your first statement created a linked server called `localhost`(a very bad and confusing idea) so you should use *that* name. It's better to use a different name though, eg "reports" for the linked server name

Comment: could you be missing a port number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sp_addlinkedserver` creates a link to a remote server having the link you give it. So I would do:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = N'reports', 
    @provider = N'SQLNCLI', 
    @datasrc = N'tcp:reports.theremotesite.net', 
    @catalog = N'master';
```

After doing so, you should have two rows in `sys.servers`, one for your local instance and one for `reports`. But you have yet to tell the link how to authenticate. To do that:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
    @rmtsrvname = N'reports', -- has to match the server name in sp_addlinkedserver
    @useself = N'False',
    @rmtuser = 'MyUsername'
    @rmtpassword = 'MyPassword';
```

Even if authentication fails, if you have got past `sp_addlinkedserver`, you have to use `sp_dropserver` to get the link out of `sys.servers`:

```
EXEC sp_dropserver N'reports'; -- has to match the server name in sp_addlinkedserver
```

Comment: This seemed to work, I just had to add `@srvproduct = N'',` into `sp_addlinkedserver` underneath `@server` otherwise I got an invalid syntax error. It was enough for me to get the right answer though, cheers!